# How to fix "cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string'" error?

Tags: c#

i'm trying to mod an existing discord bot, and i'm getting this error when i try to run it. I'm trying to make one exception when it verifies if the message was sent from a bot or not.

````cs
private async Task MessageReceivedHandler(SocketMessage msg)
        {
            try
            {

                if (msg.Author.IsBot || !_bot.Ready.Task.IsCompleted) //no bots, wait until bot connected and initialized
                throw new ArgumentNullException(msg.Author.Id == 1234)
                    return;

                if (!(msg is SocketUserMessage usrMsg))
                    return;

#if !GLOBAL_NADEKO
                // track how many messagges each user is sending
                UserMessagesSent.AddOrUpdate(usrMsg.Author.Id, 1, (key, old) => ++old);
#endif

                var channel = msg.Channel as ISocketMessageChannel;
                var guild = (msg.Channel as SocketTextChannel)?.Guild;

                await TryRunCommand(guild, channel, usrMsg).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Warn("Error in CommandHandler");
                _log.Warn(ex);
                if (ex.InnerException != null)
                {
                    _log.Warn("Inner Exception of the error in CommandHandler");
                    _log.Warn(ex.InnerException);
                }
            }
        }```
````

Comment: There's no constructor of [`ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=netframework-4.8) that takes a boolean. I'm not exactly sure what the desired outcome of `new ArgumentNullException(msg.Author.Id == 1234)` is so I can't suggest how to "fix" it.

Comment: There is no override of `ArgumentNullException`'s constructor that takes a single `bool` but only one which takes a single string which is supposed to be the name of the argument that was `null`. So `ArgumentNullException(msg.Author.Id == 1234)` is the problem. You could try to explicitly call `ToString()` like `ArgumentNullException((msg.Author.Id == 1234).ToString())` but it doesn't feel right as that's not evaluated to an argument's name and the exception isn't thrown because of a `null` check of any argument. You might [edit] your question and explain what you're actually after there.

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing `ArgumentNullException` for anything other than receiving an argument that you expect to be non-null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple issues.

First:

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(msg.Author.Id == 1234)
```

The [constructor for `ArgumentNullException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_ArgumentNullException__ctor_System_String_) takes a `string` that is supposed to be "The name of the parameter that caused the exception". You are giving it a `bool`.

But you only have one argument, and by this line you already know it's not null. So maybe just [`ArgumentException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception) is more appropriate, and write a sentence that describes why the argument is not acceptable.

Second, I don't think this does what you think it does:

```
if (msg.Author.IsBot || !_bot.Ready.Task.IsCompleted) //no bots, wait until bot connected and initialized
throw new ArgumentNullException(msg.Author.Id == 1234)
    return;
```

If an `if` statement is not followed by `{ }`, then only the one next line is considered part of the conditional code. (this is true of `for`, `foreach`, etc. - read more about ["embedded statements" here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/statements#embedded-statements))

In other words, this is the equivalent to what you have:

```
if (msg.Author.IsBot || !_bot.Ready.Task.IsCompleted) {
    throw new ArgumentNullException(msg.Author.Id == 1234)
}
return;
```

It will either throw an exception, or return. All the code after the return will never be reached. I don't think that's what you want.

This is one reason I always use braces around single-line code blocks.